# Comment module architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

> I need to build a system using ASP.NET MVC framework to add an ability
>   to add, edit and delete comments to multiple entities in my web
>   application

Namely -

> Film, Genre, Assembly, etc.

Users should be able to add comments to the above entities.

I know implementing duplicate methods (GetAllComment, PostComment, EditComment) for each entity is not recommended, so please help me with the best practice to achieve this implementation!

Any pointers will be well appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know entity framework but I'd guess those methods are defined in an interface. In which case you can comment the interface and use :

```
/// <inheritdoc/>
```

or, if there are multiple interfaces:

```
/// <inheritdoc cref="TheInterfaceName"/>
```

in the classes that implement it. This will be picked up by intellisense tooltips when you use the methods.